# Generating the checksum

Tags: c#

I have a checksum for a serial connection that is documented as such:

Formula:

```
    Chk = 0;
    for(i=0;i<Number_Of_Bytes;i++)
    {
        Chk = Chk ^ Message_Byte[i]
    }
```

my code is:

```
    public static List<byte> GetChecksum(this List<byte> source)
    {
        byte sum = 0;
        int length = source.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            sum ^= source[i];
        }

        source.Add(sum);

        return source;

    }
```

The protocol does not seem to like my checksum (it rejects my message with a checksum error response). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The protocol does not seem to like my checksum.?

Comment: Why on earth is the return type `IEnumerable<List<byte>>`?

Comment: Yeah, I am getting a checksum error back, saying my checksum is invalid.

Comment: Please note that you're modifing the source and returning it. In my opinion you should return just the checksum byte and do the `Add()` outside the method...

Comment: Yeah I looked up IEnumrable. that was stupid. Sorry im still learning this stuff.

Comment: The "Formula" is practically in C# already, yet you've gone and implemented something totally different. Just implement what the formula says?